# Are multiple 'IF Statements' correct to use?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have a two column page design in WordPress.

I would like to display a different widget based upon the allocated WordPress category in the right hand side column using a functions command.

My question is this: is my approach the 'correct method?' I have 3 sets of arrays in an "IF Statement"

**I should add that it works!**

But - I want to make sure that it is correctly done:

```
function my_custom_sidebar_display( $sidebar ) {
    // Return a different sidebar for different categories
    if ( in_category(array('Apples','Pears','Peaches')) ) {
        return 'sidebar-fruit';
    }
    if ( in_category(array('potatoes','carrots','celery')) ) {
        return 'sidebar-vegetables';
    }
  }
    if ( in_category(array('monkeys','rhino','cheetah')) ) {
        return 'sidebar-animals';
    }
    // Return theme defined sidebar area
    else {
        return $sidebar;
    }
}
add_filter( 'ocean_get_sidebar', 'my_custom_sidebar_display' );
```

Comment: normally you would use a switch statement for something like this but there's probably no harm in doing it like that as long as you're happy with it I think

Comment: @Trent But without knowing the implementation of WordPress' `in_category` function, I don't see a way of converting the OP's code into a `switch` statement.

Comment: @Trent - How would you use a  `switch/case` for the above code?

Comment: i would avoid those 4 returns with `$res =  $sidebar`at the top and only one `return $res` at the bottom. Make your debugging easier ;)

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for [Code Reviewv SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than SO.

Comment: @LoïcDiBenedetto I'm all for early returns, no point in executing unnecessary code. Especially in WordPress :-) And I would also get rid of the `else`, just use that `return $sidebar;` at the end.

Comment: even if it was able to be converted to a switch case, i dont think there are enough 'cases' to make it worthwhile anyway

Comment: You also have an extra `}` after the second `if`-statement that will end the function all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readability later and for other developers, `else if` highlights that only one statement can be true, which otherwise is not 100% obvious.

Your function would change to something like this:

```
function my_custom_sidebar_display( $sidebar ) {
    // Return a different sidebar for different categories
    if ( in_category(array('Apples','Pears','Peaches')) ) {
        return 'sidebar-fruit';
    } else if ( in_category(array('potatoes','carrots','celery')) ) {
        return 'sidebar-vegetables';
    } else if ( in_category(array('monkeys','rhino','cheetah')) ) {
        return 'sidebar-animals';
    } else { // Return theme defined sidebar area
        return $sidebar;
    }
}
```

Normally, `else if` has the advantage of being more efficient. Imagine, as suggested in the comments, you do not return immediately, but save the value in an intermediary variable and return that variable in the end:

```
if ($letter === 'a') { $value = "1";}
if ($letter === 'b') { $value = "2";}
if ($letter === 'c') { $value = "3"; }
return $value;
```

That way all 3 conditions will be checked, even though you know that only one of them can be true.
(This is just an illustration, I also think it's fine to just return immediately instead of populating another variable)

Comment: That is not true, if none of the conditions is met, the `else` will execute so this function always returns something. And as there is a `return` statement when a condition is met, there is no reason to use `else if` either.